# Proof of $\dim_K(V × W) = \dim_K(V ) + \dim_K(W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Heyho,
I have to prove the following expression:

$V$ and $W$ are vector spaces under K:

$\dim_K(V × W) = \dim_K(V ) + \dim_K(W)$

I've already proven, that:

1. $V × {0}$ and ${0} × W$ are linear subspaces of V × W
2. Given that  $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is a base of $V$ and $(w_1,...,w_n)$ is a base of $W$ $\implies$ $((v_1, 0), ... ,(v_n, 0), (0, w_1), ... , (0, w_n))$ is a base of $V × W$

It seems so logical that I can not think of a way of proving it. I mean you always build pairs from $V$ and $W$ so it seems like you just should add the two dimensions of $V$ and $W$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far so good.
First of all, $V$ and $W$ could not have the same dimension over $K$, say $\dim_K(V)=m$ and $\dim_K(W)=n$. You've already proved that, if $\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$ and $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ are basis of $V$ and $W$, respectively, then $\{(v_1,0),\dots,(v_m,0),(0,w_1),\dots,(0,w_n)\}$ is a base of $V\times W$. So, what could we say about $\dim_K(V\times W)$?

That's right! $$\dim_K(V\times W) = \#\{(v_1,0),\dots,(v_m,0),(0,w_1),\dots,(0,w_n)\}$$
$$ = m+n = \dim_K(V)+\dim_K(W)$$

Comment: k thanks, do you think that's enough? Does it really show it? Is there maybe some Definition I can use to proof the last step?

Comment: Given $B$ a basis of a vector space $V$, the dimension of $V$ is the cardinality of $B$, i.e., $\dim(V)=|B|=\#(B)$.

Comment: Or the diminsion is infinite. Then you have to proof it for the given case, right?

Comment: When we say "cardinality of $B$", the infinite case is included, but we don't say "$\dim(V)=\infty$" because it doesn't make sense